# OAuth popup being blocked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, oauth, popup

I am using http://oauth.io for connecting to Facebook, Twitter, ... in an AngularJS application. This way I don't have to worry about redirects etc and load the data when I get the access token. All that works fine, except the popup is being blocked when I trigger the popup.

The weird thing is that if you go to OAuth.io's control panel and try it to connect, it doesn't trigger the popup blocker and it works as expected. When I implement it myself, it triggers the popup warning in Chrome.

Here's my code:

**Directive:**

```
<div class="service" ng-click="addAccountToBrand(brand, service); brand.accountGridVisible = false">
  <h1>{{ service | serviceAbbreviation }}</h1>
  <p>{{ service | serviceName }}</p>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
OAuth.getData(service).then(function (oauthResult) {
  var partial = OAuthConfig[service].hasMultipleAccounts ? 'oauth-connect-multiple' : 'oauth-connect-single';
  partial = service === 'GoogleAnalytics' ? 'oauth-connect-google-analytics' : partial;

  Popover.show(partial, {
    brand: brand,
    service: service,
    serviceData: oauthResult.serviceData,
    result: oauthResult.result,
    token: oauthResult.token
  });
});
```

**Service:**

```
OAuth.popup(serviceSnakeCased, {
  state: "YOUR_SERVER_SIDE_STATE", // TODO: generate a random state
  authorize: {
    approval_prompt: 'force'
  }
}, function (error, result) {
  console.log('OAuth connection:', result);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with your code. Probably you pre-authorized popups on oauth.io? Or maybe it's a "trusted" site? Just unloading ideas...

Comment: Do you get any error in your console when triggering the popup? Also, did you name your service OAuth? Or did you extend the OAuth lib with the `getData` method?
Then, what is the version of the SDK? (You can get it by running OAuth.getVersion()). The current version is 0.2.2 (https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-js/tree/master/dist).